# How to perform php filesystem in transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions, filesystems

How to perform php filesystem with transaction?

I know it can not but wondering people usually how to solve this problem?
Each time user upload file, will insert db and store file (move_uploaded_file) into right place, need to create a new folder contain the upload file.

when user create
How to unlink file if query fail?

```
try {
  $connect_db->beginTransaction();
  // .. execute insert query
  // .. execute other query

  if (!is_dir($folder_path)) {
     if(mkdir($folder_path, 0755) == false) {
         // rollback query execute before
     }
  }

  // .. execute other query

  $connect_db->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {

}
```

when user delete
How to recover unlink file, if query fail?

```
try {
  $connect_db->beginTransaction();
  // .. execute delete query
  // .. execute other query

  if (!unlink($file_path)) {

  }

  // execute other query

  $connect_db->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {

}
```

Comment: my question is how to use unlink or other filesystem function rmdir mkdir...  make it can be rollback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that.

*Generally* filesystems do not provide any transactional features, unless you're using some exotic filesystem that does. If so - check its documentation.

> If query fail, how to remove the file? (question)

Using [unlink()](http://php.net/unlink)

> How to recover unlink file, if query fail?

Just don't delete immediately. Schedule the removal task and cancel it if required.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know it can not, but wondering people usually how to solve this kind of problem?  now I'm using cron just clean the file but seems stupid

Comment: @user1775888: what problem actually? You haven't explained any problems in the question.

Comment: please see my update, I know it can use unlink but I don't know how to, can you show some example how to put into my example code, thanks

Comment: @user1775888: put it in your `catch`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the class for managing the transaction.

For example:

```
class Archivo {

    private static $filesPendingDelete = array();

    public static function commit(){
        foreach (self::$filesPendingDelete as $file){
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                unlink($file);
            }else{
                throw new Exception('the file does not exite: '.$file);
            }
        }
        self::$filesPendingDelete = array();
    }

    public static function rollBack(){
        self::$filesPendingDelete = array();
    }


    private $path;

    public function __construct($path) {
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            $this->setPath($path);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Invalid path '.$path);
        }
    }

    public function getPath() {
        return $this->path;
    }

    private function setPath($path) {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function delete() {
        if (file_exists($this->getPath())) {
            self::$filesPendingDelete[] = $this->getPath();
        } else {
            throw new Exception('the file does not exite: '.$this->getPath());
        }
    }

}
```

Example of use:

```
require_once 'Archivo.php';

try {
    /*
      Other code.....
     */

    $file1 = new Archivo('test1.jpg');

    $file2 = new Archivo('test2.jpg');

    $file1->delete();

    $file2->delete();

    Archivo::commit();

} catch (Exception $ex) {

    Archivo::rollBack();
}
```

luck and good code!, 
by MundialSYS